# HOWTO: Center a box in the vertical and horizontal middle of the screen and show other boxed underneath

Tags: html, css

Like said in the title I would like to 
center some box (lets say login box) in the middle of a screen.
Under this box I would like to show several other boxes (additional information/disclaimer etc.)

Edit:
to be more precise: the centered login box, must be vertical and horizontal centered and stay there. The additional boxes should appear underneath the centered login box.

What would be the easiest way todo it?

HTML:

```
<div id="centeredBox">
    I am centered and have some undefined size (cause I could display some image
</div>
<div id="underCenteredBox">
    underCenteredBox
</div>
<div id="underUnderCenteredBox">
    underUnderCenteredBox
</div>
```

CSS:
#

```
centeredBox {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        /* bring your own prefixes */
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    }

#underCenteredBox {
        ???
    }

#underUnderCenteredBox {
        ???
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1t4d5odu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "outer"/"center" wrapper is displayed as table/cell with centered content (here we could use flex as well but with less browser support).

Your "centeredBox" is display as an inline element and adjust to its parent "center/middle" rules.

And then the "under-the-centeredBox" boxes has an "inner" wrapper, which use positioning, making them start at your "centeredBox" bottom.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrap-outer {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrap-center {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrap-inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#centeredBox {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
    padding: 10px;
}
#underCenteredBox {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ccc;        
}
#underUnderCenteredBox {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-outer">
    <div class="wrap-center">
        <div id="centeredBox">
            I am centered and have some undefined size<br />
            as in 2 or<br />
            3 lines of text ... and an image<br />
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/100/sports" />
            <div class="wrap-inner">
                <div id="underCenteredBox">
                    underCenteredBox
                </div>
                <div id="underUnderCenteredBox">
                    underUnderCenteredBox
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer I was looking for. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Your're welcome .. and I added an explanation as well, how/why it works.

Answer (score 2):

`Try this`    https://jsfiddle.net/83ad3825/

Is this something you looking for?

Comment: Hi Yas, thanks for your help: Sadly is is   bit more complicated. The top box must be vertically and horizontally centered on the screen all the time, the additional boxes underneath.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly what you asked for an easy approach to achieve a similar result is to simply wrap the cenetered container and put additional content within this wrapper.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t4d5odu/1/)

```
<div id="centeredBoxWrapper">
    <div id="centeredBox">
        I am centered and have some undefined size (cause I could display some image
    </div>
    <div id="underCenteredBox">
    underCenteredBox
    </div>
    <div id="underUnderCenteredBox">
        underUnderCenteredBox
    </div>
</div>

#centeredBoxWrapper {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        /* bring your own prefixes */
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

#centeredBox{
            border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
}
```

Comment: Hi Hosch Nok, thanks for your answer. I think my description was not good enough  the top login box should be vertically and horizontally centered all the time, the other boxes appear underneath.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1t4d5odu/2/)

You have to wrap your `div`s into a wrapper div and make the wrapper div fixed positioned. See the HTML and CSS below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="centeredBox">I am centered and have some undefined size (cause I could display some image</div>
    <div id="underCenteredBox">underCenteredBox</div>
    <div id="underUnderCenteredBox">underUnderCenteredBox</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#centeredBox {
    position:relative;
    /* bring your own prefixes */
    border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
}
#underCenteredBox {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffe1;
    position: relative;
}
#underUnderCenteredBox {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffe1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Same as my solution. But this centers the wrapper, but not the centered box. I think the centered box should be in the middle while the containers under it could even overflow the screen.

Comment: The OP has not specified exactly what his requirement is..anyway he has 2 options..let him select.. ;)

Comment: He did. He wants a box centered. Afterwards add boxes under this centered box (which could possibly overflow). In your example the centered box will go to the top of the screen when adding content to the wrapper.

Comment: Nearly ;) I added some additional information to make, the top box, should always be vertical and horizontal centered. The additional boxes appear underneath the centered one.

Comment: Yes, I used LGSons aproach :)